# Youtube Video Player that plays video in same spot on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a project that is a navigation and a video player in the same div container.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W49lY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s89Oy.png

Once you click on one of the four boxes, another video will pop up and show in that same position.

Which approach should I go with? HTML/JavaScript?

I am totally new to JavaScript, so I know that this code is wrong, but this is what I have so far.

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-left: auto;">
      <div> 
    <button onclick="Word()">Word</button> 
    <button onclick="Excel()">Excel</button>
    <button onclick="PowerPoint()">PowerPoint</button>
    <button onclick="OneNote()">OneNote</button>
    <br><br>
    <video id="word" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-nHYzK-BVg"></video>
    <video id="excel" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-nHYzK-BVg"></video>
  <video id="powerpoint" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-nHYzK-BVg"></video>
  <video id="onenote" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-nHYzK-BVg"></video>
   </div> 

   <script> 
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("word");

  function Word() { 
      if (myVideo.onClick) 
         myVideo.play(); 
     else 
         myVideo.pause(); 
  } 

  function Excel() { 
   
      myVideo.play(); 
     else
      myVideo.pause();
  } 

  function PowerPoint() { 
      myVideo.play();
     else
      myVideo.pause(); 
  } 

  function OneNote() { 
      myVideo.play();
     else
      myVideo.pause(); 
  } 
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use one function called videoSelect() and change the HTML content of a div with the id of player when the button is clicked.

innerHTML is used to change the html content of an element. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

(this.id) retrieves the button's id and passes it to your videoSelect function.

this.id = element

Full example here -> https://codepen.io/chaosmaths/pen/aKmOVm/

As a note the video URLs in your post were the same for all of the examples so  I've changed the URLs to what I believe are the videos you wanted. If they aren't just change the URL in corresponding variable. You can also use the video tag instead of iframe. I just used that because it is what YouTube provides with their embed codes.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="options">
    <button id="word" onclick="videoSelect(this.id)">Word</button>
    <button id="excel" onclick="videoSelect(this.id)">Excel</button>
    <button id="powerpoint" onclick="videoSelect(this.id)">PowerPoint</button>
    <button id="onenote" onclick="videoSelect(this.id)">OneNote</button>
  </div>

  <div id="player"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#options{
  text-align: center;
}
#player{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

JS

```
var word = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/S-nHYzK-BVg';
var excel = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rwbho0CgEAE';
var powerpoint = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/XF34-Wu6qWU';
var onenote = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/qN15XnU96vQ';

var player = document.getElementById('player');
function videoSelect(element){
  if (element === "word"){
    player.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + word + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  }
   if (element === "excel"){
    player.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + excel + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  }
   if (element === "powerpoint"){
    player.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + powerpoint + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  }
   if (element === "onenote"){
    player.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + onenote + '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow! this is the exact thing that I have been looking for! Thank you so much @C.S. Wright

One last thing, how would I make the first "Word" video show up by default?

Comment: Just put the word video element inside the player div. It will change when a button for another video is clicked.  I've updated the example to reflect this change. Glad this was helpful.

Comment: <div id="player">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S-nHYzK-BVg" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks so much! @C.S. Wright, works flawlessly.